# Wordpress: How to show only tags without containing numbers?

Tags: php, string, wordpress, tags, remove-if

I need a solution, that enables me to show below a listing on a wordpress page only tags that don't contain a number.

This is my code:

```
<?php

        $tags_html = '';
            foreach($tags as $single_tag) 
             {

$count++;
if (1 == $count)
 {
  $tags_html .= '<a href="'.get_term_link($single_tag, 'spot_tags').'">'.$single_tag->name.'</a>, ';
}
                //// ADDS TO OUR MARKUP

            }
            //// TRIMS LAST COME
            echo rtrim($tags_html, ', ');

        ?>
    </span> 



    <?php }
    ?>
```

All tags that belongs to a Post/Listing that contains a number should not be show, tags that did not contain a number could be shown below the listing.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

I can't know the exact structure of `$single_tag` unless you post a `var_dump()` of it, but here's the `if` code you would need to prevent displaying tags with numeric content:

```
if(!preg_match('/\d/',$single_tag))
{
    $tags_html .= '<a href="'.get_term_link($single_tag, 'spot_tags').'">'.$single_tag->name.'</a>, ';
}
```

It uses the [\d regular expression escape sequence](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php#layout-content) to check if the string contains numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If your tags are in a string, you would need these two lines (to build an array)

```
$string = '34hj, wer, wer35, rwer, 5345, 5dgg45, sdfa';
$tags = explode(',', $string);
```

otherwise, if your tags are already in an array, like below, you don't need the above

```
$tags = array('34hj', 'wer', 'wer35', 'rwer', '5345', '5dgg45', 'sdfa');
```

and finally, you need this snippet which will exclude tags that contain any number.

```
foreach($tags as $tag) {
    if(preg_match('/^[^\d]+$/', $tag));
    echo trim($tag) . "\n";
}
```

[Working demo](http://ideone.com/aMJLWB)